# Chroma Key replace green color part with another image using FFMPEG

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, chromakey, color-key

[Chroma Key Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk2PD.jpg)

I want to replace green color of the above chromekey image with another image. The image should only replace with the green color not overlay entire image.

I am using following sample command below but it overlay the entire image not only the green color.

-y -i /storage/emulated/0/dummyResized.jpg -i /storage/emulated/0/circularImage.png -filter_complex [1:v]colorkey=green:0.3:0.2[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay[out] -map [out] /storage/emulated/0/outputBlackCircular.jpg

Comment: What do the two images look like?

Comment: "-y -i " + backgroundPath+ " -i /storage/emulated/0/ScaledOutput.jpg -filter_complex [1:v]chromakey=green:0.13:0.2[ckout];[0:v][ckout]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[o] -map [o] -map 1:a? -c:a copy " + dest.getPath()   Solved using this

Comment: @WelbornMachado from above command image only place at the center of the base image. Is there any solution for placing an image exactly where green part is?